# Documentation on what data to get from Spotify / Facebook

Tags: spotify

We are working on an app with it's own user database. We are looking into integration with social networks and wonder if there is any documentation on what integration is possible with Spotify and our app? Can there be done more than search and lookup?

Is the stuff Spotify is sharing with Facebook only limited to Facebook, or could we possibly also access this information from Spotify?

Would you know if Facebook shares the Spotify data which is on Facebook with third parties through API's?

cheers

Comment: I don't know but I'd be surprised if the words "share", "facebook" and "data" went well together in the same sentence. Data is how they make their money after all.

Answer (score 1):

Using Facebook's APIs you can request a person's listens, but that includes everything that uses Facebook's listen API, not just Spotify. Spotify's interaction with that API is private and not available to third parties.

Spotify itself doesn't provide any social data via APIs.